# Getting a Parser error for one of my contracts

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721

I'm getting the error:

> "ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration
> expected. --> CurrentERC721.sol:1393:1: | 1393 | contract
> ERC721Pausable is ERC721, Pausable { | ^^^^^^^^"

The code I have here:

```
contract ERC721Pausable is ERC721, Pausable {

   function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual override {
      super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

      require(!paused(), "ERC721Pausable: token transfer while paused");
   }
}
```

I'm a bit confused because the formatting seems good, along with the semicolons. Could it be a placement of this contract issue?